# Functional Operations to iterate arrays in Java 8

Tags: java, functional-programming

So in an attempt to keep up with the times, I would like to learn what I can about Java 8's new functional operations. Beyond the opinions of which looks nicer, which is totally opinion based, would someone like to describe in detail the positives(and possibly negatives) in using Java 8's new functional programming style to iterate arrays?

This is what I mean:

Pre-Java 8:

```
    for(Object item: itemList){
        item.doSomething();
    }
```

Java 8:

```
    itemList.stream().forEach((item) -> {
        item.doSomething();
    });
```

The answers have enlightened me, so I will write something to demonstrate it's potential.

```
    static int pos = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Worker> workers = Arrays.asList(new Worker[1000]);
        workers.replaceAll(worker -> new Worker(pos++));
        workers.parallelStream().forEach(Worker::startJob);
    }

    public static class Worker {
        final int pos;

        public Worker(int pos) {
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        public synchronized void startJob() {
            try {
                wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.global.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("Finished... " + pos);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a poor comparison because they aren't equivalent. The latter is potentially lazy, so it can be efficiently combined with other operations.

Comment: It is a matter of taste and opinion. There's no direct, simple answer. For some scenarios, the functional approach is better, while for others, sticking to imperative is the best option.

Comment: Just my opinion, but the "more beautiful" Java 8+ way to write it would be `itemList.stream().forEach(Item::doSomething);`

Comment: The major advantage is executing the operation in parallel if its not stateful, simply replace stream with parallelStream.

Comment: Because your getting rid of the "how" and leaving the "what".  Your code should look this this.  itemList.forEach(Item::doSomething);  This code is as readable as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a partial answer, but the general point of the iterators is moving from *external* iteration to *internal* iteration. The `foreach` just a replacement, but consider something like the following (from *Java 8 Lambdas*) simulating the throwing of two dice:

```
public Map < Integer, Double > parallelDiceRolls() { 
  double fraction = 1.0 / N; 
  return IntStream.range( 0, N) .parallel()
    .mapToObj( twoDiceThrows())
    .collect( groupingBy( side -> side, summingDouble( n -> fraction)));
}
```

This is running a parallel operation against the stream, removing all external iteration requirements and all manual threading requirements. It replaces 50-60 lines of code.

It also moves from a focus on how to accomplish something (such as the OP's pre-Java 8 example) to what to accomplish.

Consider a `Artist` class that has an `.isFrom(String)` method. In the OP's first example, to count how many are from Liverpool, the code would be something like:

```
int count = 0; 
for (Artist artist : allArtists) {
  if (artist.isFrom("Liverpool")) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Notice that the the desire to accumulate is lost in the loop and the filtering. Contrast with:

```
allArtists.stream()
  .filter(artist -> artist.isFrom("Liverpool")
  .count();
```

Now the logic is clear -- a filtering and a count. The iteration is now internal rather than external.

There are many additional examples, rationales, and preferences. But I think it is more than "beauty" -- it is a focus on the what, not the how when one considers iteratation.

Comment: I get that you put some work into this answer but this is a question asking for an opinion and as such should be closed and not answered.

Comment: @bhspencer, while I agree it is an opinion question and should be closed, the general point of whether the iteration is merely cluttering and not revealing is of some interest. It is not a conclusive or final answer, but it does address the primary point of the OP.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the .parallel() function, this immediately made the positives become MUCH more apparent. 

No, I was not looking for opinions.

I was asking for more information on the positives and negatives BEYOND opinion.

Comment: I do not disagree that it is a fine answer to the question posed but since the question is of a form that is unsuitable for SO I feel compelled to discourage   users from answering it.

Comment: "unsuitable for SO" What exactly makes a question "suitable". I think these responses are the only thing "unsuitable" for SO. You all are taking it very personally that I wanted actual tangible benefits to using lambdas that has nothing to do with coding style, which itself is opinion based.

Comment: @RichardSmith use of internal or external iteration is really just a question of preferred style. Both approaches achieve the same goals. What kind of advantage are you thinking of? There is no performance advantage, modern compilers will unroll loops and function calls. It all comes down to how you as a programmer prefer to express your ideas.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I apologize a bit, as the "opinion" aspect to which I was referring was the "beauty" (it being in the eye of the beholder and such). But the basic question of whether the the iteration approach of Java 8 can convey definitive benefits is, IMHO, a very good one. And the ability (with caveats, of course) to quickly convert to parallel processing is one of them. Furthermore, I would submit that a focus on what not how is always of interest -- it is better expressiveness that is beyond programmer preference.

Comment: "definitive benefit" is an opinion. Yes it can be fewer lines of code to turn a functional approach into a parallel solution and this comes at the cost of code that is more complicated to step through with a debugger. You are not going to get an answer that tells you definitively that one approach has an advantoge over the other only the opinions of those that use them.

Comment: Another uptight SO fight.

Comment: @NickZiebert what is fighty about it? The question was closed as primarily opinion based. The OP wanted to engage in discussion about why it was considered an opinion. Since I voted to close I was willing to take the time to express my reasons for closing. The only comment that digresses from topic is yours.

Comment: @bhspencer Hey spence, I'm curious why you consider yourself the white knight of the SO website.  What do you have to gain to spend 20 minutes banging on about why this isn't good for SO?